# C# TPL Dataflow - Completion not working

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, pipeline, tpl-dataflow

This code never reaches the last line because the completion doesn't propagate from the saveBlock to the sendBlock. What am I doing wrong?

```
var readGenerateBlock = new TransformBlock<int, int>(n =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Read " + n);
        Thread.Sleep(15);
        return n;
    }); 
var groupingBlock = new BatchBlock<int>(10);
var saveBlock = new TransformManyBlock<int[], int>(n =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Saving {0} items [{1}; {2}]", n.Count(), n.First(), n.Last());
        Thread.Sleep(150);
        return n;
    }); 
var sendBlock = new TransformBlock<int, int>(n =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Sending {0}", n);
        Thread.Sleep(25);
        return n;
    }, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2 }); 

readGenerateBlock.LinkTo(groupingBlock, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });
groupingBlock.LinkTo(saveBlock, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });
saveBlock.LinkTo(sendBlock, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });

Parallel.For(0, 250, i => readGenerateBlock.Post(i));
readGenerateBlock.Complete();

sendBlock.Completion.Wait();
Console.WriteLine("Completed.");
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to read the data out of the block before it will be completed. Since noöne is reading `saveBlock`, it will never be completed.

If you don't need the data, the easiest solution is to use `ActionBlock` instead of `TransformBlock`. Otherwise, just keep reading the data until the block is completed.

Comment: According to the official documentation: *'Signals to the System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow.IDataflowBlock that it should not accept nor produce any more messages nor consume any more postponed messages.' *However, what you are saying is true, sounds a little bit contradicting