# TPL Dataflow CompletionPropagation with not working MaxMessage - Option not working

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

I already checked this post:
[C# TPL Dataflow - Completion not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31915295/c-sharp-tpl-dataflow-completion-not-working) (but adding a NullTarget will not change the outcome here)

and a few more.

However I am not getting why this example is not completing:

```
private static async Task WriteIntDelayed(int delay_ms, string name, int? i)
{
    await Task.Delay(delay_ms);
    await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync(name + "\t" + (i.HasValue ? i.ToString() : "null"));
}
private static int counter = 0;
public static async Task ExecuteMultipleSuccessorsSampleAsync()
{
    TransformBlock<string, int?> tb = new TransformBlock<string, int?>(
                s =>
                {
                    if (Int32.TryParse(s, out int result))
                    {
                        return result;
                    }
                    else
                        return null;
                });

    ActionBlock<int?> ab1 = new ActionBlock<int?>(async (int? i) => await WriteIntDelayed(10, $"ab1[{counter++}]", i));
    ActionBlock<int?> ab2 = new ActionBlock<int?>(
        async (int? i)
            => await WriteIntDelayed(500, $"ab2[{counter++}]", i)
        , new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { BoundedCapacity = 1 });
    ActionBlock<int?> ab3 = new ActionBlock<int?>(
        async (int? i)
            => await WriteIntDelayed(200, $"ab3[{counter++}]", i),
        new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions { BoundedCapacity = 1 });

    tb.LinkTo(ab1, new DataflowLinkOptions { MaxMessages = 10, PropagateCompletion = true });
    tb.LinkTo(ab2, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });
    tb.LinkTo(ab3, new DataflowLinkOptions { PropagateCompletion = true });


    // Parallel.For(0, 30, (i, state) =>
    // {
    //     tb.Post(i.ToString());
    // });

    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
    {
        tb.Post(i.ToString());
    }

    tb.Complete();
    await Task.WhenAll(
        ab1.Completion /*will NOT complete */, 
        ab2.Completion /*will complete */, 
        ab3.Completion /*will complete */);
}
```

Comment: Dataflow completion works. The question you linked to had a bug - it forgot to read the output data so the block couldn't complete.

Comment: in the example above, it does not, ab1 will NOT complete, while ab2 and ab3 will.

Comment: Linking doesn't mean broadcasting. The way this code is written a) all messages will go to `ab1` unless it has a bounded capacity

Comment: I suspect you already noticed that and used `MaxMessages` to force messages to go to the other blocks.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes this is by intentation

Comment: That's not what it does. You should have set the `BoundedCapacity` of the action blocks. MaxMessages is rarely used because it controls *unlinking* after that number of messages. That's shown in the docs [How to: Unlink Dataflow Blocks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-unlink-dataflow-blocks)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks a lot! Also thanks for the link. It would be nice if they also mention this in the [API - Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.dataflowlinkoptions.maxmessages?view=netcore-2.2#System_Threading_Tasks_Dataflow_DataflowLinkOptions_MaxMessages), there it is not mentioned

Comment: It is surprising that blocks will now broadcast completion. That never was the case before unless I'm just completely off base. But glad you got things squared away.